# Center ppt slide title

Tags: r, powerpoint, reporters

Using `ReporteRs` package we can create power point presenation from R code.
I tried to create a power point slide having a **centered** title.

Here the basic code I am using to create the slide:

```
library( ReporteRs )
mydoc = pptx( ) # try adding argument: template = 'template.pptx' here
mydoc = addSlide( mydoc, "Title and Content" )
mydoc = addTitle( mydoc, "This is a title" )
writeDoc( mydoc, "pp_simple_example.pptx" )
```

This creates a slide with title positioned at the left. Unfortunately `addTitle` don't expose any argument to format text or change its position. I looked also in the package options :

```
 options()[grep('ReporteRs',names(options()))]
```

but without success.

Comment: Looking at the docs (https://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/powerpoint.html#UIDOGY85lT7OO) it looks like you can accomplish this by giving it a template to work from, where that slide template has the placement that you want already defined.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen thanks. looking as interesting idea.Even I don't see if there is a duplicate function to copy existing slide or update existing one.

Comment: I added a comment to your question code, where I believe you can specify a template.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use a predefined template (as commented below my question)
To create a template:

1. Create a presentation
2. Choose a template where the text is centered. You can add a dummy slide with text and choose one from the predefined themes ( Design tab)
3. Don't forget to remove the slide. and save the presentation as `basic_template.ppx`

Now in the R code to use this template :

```
mydoc = pptx( template='basic_template.pptx') ## give the whole path here
```